# Постраничный вывод информации в GridView с использованием  LinqDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, gridview

Доброго времени суток. 
Нужно вывести по 5 записей на странице с возможностью перехода на другую страницу.

Технология `Asp.Net WebForms`

Решил использовать для этого `GridView` а для заполнения данными `LinqDataSource`.

Создаю сам грид

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees"
    runat="server"
    AllowPaging="True"
    PageSize="5"
    AllowSorting="True"
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1"
    EmptyDataText="Элементов нет"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField SortExpression="Title" DataField="EmployeeId" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField SortExpression="Title" DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField SortExpression="Title" DataField="EmployeeSalary" HeaderText="Salary" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" OnSelecting="LinqDataSource1_Selecting"></asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Заполняю его так:

```
 protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
       e.Result = from p in _employees
                       select new
                       {
                           EmployeeId = p.EmployeeId,
                           EmployeeName = p.EmployeeName,
                           EmployeeSalary = p.CalculateMonthlySalary()
                       };

    }
```

Проблема в том, что при перехоже по страницам идет загрузка данных по новой и добавление этих данных в `GridViev`.

Как правильно сделать постраничный вывод данных?

Правильна ли такая реализация?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рабочая версия (могу скинуть проект):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees"
    runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True"
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" 
    PageSize="5" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField SortExpression="Title" DataField="EmployeeId" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField SortExpression="Title" DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField SortExpression="Title" DataField="EmployeeSalary" HeaderText="Salary" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" AutoGenerateOrderByClause="True" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" OnSelecting="LinqDataSource1_Selecting"></asp:LinqDataSource>

protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
   var query = from p in _employees
                   select new
                   {
                       EmployeeId = p.EmployeeId,
                       EmployeeName = p.EmployeeName,
                       EmployeeSalary = p.CalculateMonthlySalary()
                   };

    e.Result = query;

}
```

Comment: Не выходит. при такой реализации пропадают кнопки перехода по страницам...:(

Comment: Вы оба решения одновременно использовали? Исправьте только код

Comment: Я попробовал оба варианта по очереди. 
Если использовать строку 

e.Result = query.Skip(gvEmployees.PageIndex * PAGE_SIZE).Take(PAGE_SIZE);
или 
query =  query.Skip(gvEmployees.PageIndex * PAGE_SIZE).Take(PAGE_SIZE);
e.Result = query;

То пропадают кнопки навигации. если не использовать эту строку, то происходить полная загрузка данных.:(

Comment: попробуйте второй вариант, при этом у GridView поставьте AutoPage="false"

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees"

        runat="server"

        AutoPage="false"

        AllowPaging="True"

        PageSize="<%# PAGE_SIZE %>"

        AllowSorting="True"

        DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1"

        EmptyDataText="Элементов нет"

        AutoGenerateColumns="false">


таже проблема. не отображаются кнопки навигации.
если поставить AutoPage="true" - тоже.
если изменять значения AllowPaging - тоже самое:(

Comment: обновил ответ, посмотрите, должно работать. если нужно, то скину тестовый проект.